# Swap right-most N bits between two integers

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

This question was asked during an onsite C++ coding interview.  I did NOT provide a good answer during that interview.  So I was hoping to get feedback and suggestions from folks here at stack overflow.  Now that I've had some more time to come up with a solution, I believe that I wrote a decent solution. I think this works OK as along as `a` and `b` refer to different integers.  If `a` and `b` refer to the same integer, then that integer would be be clobbered to 0.

```
void SwapRightMostNBits(int& a, int& b, unsigned int n){

    if (n>31) { n=31; }
    int mask=static_cast<int>(pow(2,n)-1);

    a ^= (b & mask);
    b ^= (a & mask);
    a ^= (b & mask);
}
```

Comment: If `n > 31` why would you set it to 31? I would at least consider > 31 as out of range and not swap anything in that case. Also, you can easily compute `mask = (1 << n) - 1;`. You don't want/need `pow`.

Comment: pow for integers --> interview fail, next.

Comment: instead of pow(2,n) use 1 << n, perform bit operations on unsigned int values

Comment: That's not an interview fail. Who really cares. One could argue that you should say what you mean. Shifting is not important here.

Comment: Depends who is interviewing for what job, but it can be taken as a pretty bad sign. Anyway, there are too many bit operations in what the OP is proposing.

Comment: You assume `sizeof(int) == 4` and `CHAR_BIT == 8`. Neither are guaranteed.

Comment: @Frank: Merely that `sizeof(int)*CHAR*BIT==32`. There are two other ways in which that can be achieved.

Comment: @Ron: I tend to start with one such question. If you made it to the interview, this should be easy. And even if you're a bit junior, it should help with the nerves. I don't _really_ care about the answer; it's more a way for me to judge what to ask next.

Comment: Also, I personally would never pull out a cutesy XOR trick in an interview context. Iit reeks of memorization, instead of problem solving, and is something I use so rarely I would be worried of getting it wrong. I would have just done a regular swap with a `temp` variable, and mentioned a XOR trick as an alternative.

Answer (score 6):

I think the intended trick here is

```
void SwapRightMostNBits(unsigned int& a, unsigned int& b, unsigned int n){

    unsigned int mask=(1U<<n) -1;
    unsigned int diff = (a^b) & mask;

    a ^= diff;
    b ^= diff;
}
```

Note that this uses 3 XOR's, like your solution, but only one masking operation.  Plus, this is way friendlier on the CPU registers. There are no false dependency chains. And finally, it works if `&a==&b`.

Comment: by "false dependency chains", you mean Load-Hit-Store, right?

Comment: Thanks MSalters, this looks like a better solution!

Comment: @Frank: No, that's when a single value gets moved back and forth from memory. Modern CPU's try to execute N instructions in parallel, and that's only possible if the N'th instruction doesn't depend on the previous N-1 instructions. That's why a CPU dynamically figures out dependency relations, and these can be chained. The "classical XOR swap" suffers from the problem that the final A value depends on both A and B because they are XOR'ed together, and so does B, which means that the first XOR has to finish before the next operation starts.

Comment: @MSalters That was my concern. The removal of OP's LHS makes a much larger impact than freeing up OOO execution (probably around 10 times more depending on the CPU pipeline).

Comment: @Frank: Well, they tie together. OOOE also allows you to start a new instruction while waiting for a load instruction. In my example, `a^b` can start immediately. It may take a while before `a^b` finishes, but when it does the mask is available.